# Shopware 6 Store-API set newsletter recipient tags

Tags: shopware

I'm trying to add a newsletter recipient through store-api, which works. But when I try to add a tag inside the request, it fails. The documentation states that it is possible to add a tag as a string to the request, see [here](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/storeapi.json/paths/%7E1newsletter%7E1subscribe/post)

My request looks like the following:

```
POST /store-api/newsletter/subscribe
{"option":"subscribe","email":"email@email.com","storefrontUrl":"http://myhost.test","tags":"men"}
```

I also tried to make the tags value an array, but this doesn't work either. How do I add a tag to the newsletter recipient through the store API?

Answer (score 1):

As of Version 6.4.3.0 this seems not possible.

I tried the same request as you, as well as

```
"tags":["men"]
```

and

```
"tags":["uuidOfExistingTagGoesHere"]
```

all does not work.

Also the doc block for tags is wrong (it says "zip code" instead of a useful description).

In addition I tried to assign existing tags - this is what works via the admin API:

```
"tags": [
  {
    "id": "80df380188364f3c9bbaaa4d6b993dbd"
  },
  {
    "id": "108428f0a37c4d11a66976adc5337c23"
  }
]
```

Which still returns

```
"code": "FRAMEWORK__WRITE_MALFORMED_INPUT",
"title": "Bad Request",
"detail": "Expected data to be array.",
```

Also looking [at the code](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/ecaf75a8d69576caca1ce49f6e60bed296c004e1/src/Core/Content/Newsletter/SalesChannel/NewsletterSubscribeRoute.php#L244) there currently seems no handling of the tags. As far as I understand it, the tags would needed to be created on the fly

A possible fix would be the following code:

```
if (isset($data['tags']) { // inserted that lines
    $data['tags'] = $data['tags']->all(); 
} // end inserted lines
$data = $this->completeData($data, $context);
```

Using that line, the last mentioned request works (you could then use the IDs of *existing* newsletter recipient tags).
Of course in this case the API docs have to be adapted.

TL;DR

In my opinion, this seems a flaw in the current Store API implementation.
I would suggest to create an issue on the [Shopware 6 issue tracker](https://issues.shopware.com/?products=SW-6).